# How to select schema at runtime using Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jdbctemplate

I already have an existing code base, where schema(like db_1, db_2..) are created at run time.

We are currently using JdbcTemplate, using that its quite easy to append schema in the native SQL queries some thing like :-

```
sql = " Select * from "+schema+".user";
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new UserMapper());
```

Now I want to know is how to provide schema to hibernate at runtime like I did with the jdbcTemplate?

What connection url should I provide in hibernate.cfg.xml so that it doesn't connects to a single schema rather whole database?

Any suggestions will be helpfull.

P.S: I am new to hibernate (So I might have missed something stupid)

Comment: have you tried hibernates HibernateInterceptor?

Comment: Maybe this could help you, worth to read https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-dynamic-table-routin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know of two options:

1. Use native SQL query binding results to JPA entities. Details [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql).
2. Use Hibernate multi-tenancy. Details [here](https://www.ricston.com/blog/multitenancy-jpa-spring-hibernate-part-1/) and [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy).

Although I haven't tried either.